# mod_rewrite all requests on a folder except one

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

There are many similar questions but none of the provided solutions fits my need.

I want to forward all requests on a folder to a certain url, except one request should be forwarded to another url.
here's what I got so far:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/test/test.html$<br />
RewriteRule .? http://www.example.com [L,NC,QSA]
```

now what's missing is that the request /test/test.html should be forwarded to
www.example.com/test/index.html

What I'm trying is to protect any request on that folder (test) except someone knows a certain url (test/test.html), then it should be forwarded to test/index.html

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for

```
# internally redirect /test/test.html to /test/index.html
RewriteRule ^test/test\.html$ /test/index.html [L]
# don't do any more rewrites on the url: /test/index.html
RewriteRule ^test/index\.html$ - [L]
# internally redirect all (other) request to the root
RewriteRule .* / [L]
```

Comment: Thanks Gerben, but the first call is still redirecting to http://www.example.com. I guess it's because after the first rule is appended it will call a new request and the second rule is applied!? Any hints about that?

Comment: Since 'example.com' was in the rewrite, I assumed it was another host, and you wanted a redirect. See edit above with the new code

Comment: sorry it's the same host. strangely I get redirected to /test/test.html whatever url I use. it seems the [L] flag is not correctly applied.

Comment: That's rather strange. Are there any other rules inside your htaccess?

Comment: There is a RewriteCond for file access in the /test/ folder. but that should not apply as the redirect never arrives in that folder.